# Issue with checkbox aria-label which is coming as blank

Tags: html, accessibility

I have the following code:

```html
<label class="el-checkbox el-transfer-panel__item"><span class="el-checkbox__input"><span class="el-checkbox__inner"></span><input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="el-checkbox__original" value="6" aria-labelledby="checkbox_5" id="checkbox_5"></span><span class="el-checkbox__label"><span>Total amount due</span><!----></span></label>
```

Every time I move my keys over it, the speech viewer shows blank. I tried many ways to fix it but its always showing the blank

Comment: Additionally to the answer already given, you should also remove aria-hidden=false. It is totally useless and older screen readers have all the chance to misinterpret it as aria-hidden=true, which is a catastrophy.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is in how you are using `aria-labelledby`. This property should point to the ID of something which describes the item. In your code, you are pointing the element at itself which doesn't give it any details to work with.

The `<label>` property is what a screen-reader would refer to and that requires a `for=""` value (which your markup doesn't have). The code below illustrates a better way to approach this for accessibility.

```html
<label for="checkboxID">
  <div class="el-checkbox__input">
    <div class="el-checkbox__inner"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxName" id="checkboxID"> <span class="el-checkbox__label">Total amount due</span>
  </div>
</label>
```

I have swapped the `<span>` tags for `<div>` because span tags should only be used for inline elements and shouldn't be used to wrap around block-level elements (such as the `<input>`).

Here's an [example from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby) of how you could use aria with a checkbox:

```html
<span role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="tac"></span>
<span id="tac">I agree to the Terms and Conditions.</span>
```

Comment: This example is better than the original but you don't need the `for` attribute because the `<input>` and the text label are both children of the `<label>` so there's an implicit association of the label to the checkbox.  It doesn't really hurt anything to have `for` but I like to keep my code minimal.  You can remove `for` and this answer will work just fine.

Comment: @slugolicious, thanks for commenting on this - a very good suggestion on how to minimise the code needed!

Comment: But That does not work for Element UI el-transfer Tag, i tried everything you mentioned but it always shows me blank

Comment: @Neeza, could you share a screenshot of what you are seeing in the browser? I've pasted the code in and it appears to be showing up OK in the accessibility tab of Firefox (http://prntscr.com/vnF2yxZ8Lx8Z)

Comment: firefox seems to be bring in the data but chrome is a problem right now